# How can I make the HTTP request object visible to my winston logger?

Tags: nestjs, winston

I'm building a [NestJS](https://nestjs.com/) based application and using [nest-winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nest-winston) for logging.

I would like to log the incoming request header with every log message. For that I need to somehow extract the HTTP context from `nestjs` and pass it to `nest-winston`.

I'm unable to find how to do either. If this is not doable in `nest-winston` I don't mind using `winston` directly.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge it isn't doable with the `nest-winston` module because its logger is not [`REQUEST` scoped](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/injection-scopes). You'll need to create your own [dynamic module](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/dynamic-modules) and have your service as `REQUEST` scoped. Then you can use `@Inject(REQUEST)` to have the request added to each instance of the winston service you'd create.

With that said, there are some drawbacks to request scoped classes, namely resource consumption as not only will the service have to be re-instantiated, but every service that depends on that winston service, and then every service up the line until you reach the controller. Just something to keep in mind

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you mean by re-instantiated? Can you walk me through what's happening? is this nest specific or more of a general concept you can guide me to a study material I can go through?

Comment: As everything in Nest is class based, classes must be created (instantiated) before they can be used. In the case of `REQUEST` scoped classes, on each new request, each class that is about to be used will need to be re-created, from the class that starts the REQUEST scope, all the way up to the Controller. [There's more information here](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/injection-scopes) from Nest's documentation that explains it a little more clearly than is possible in a comment

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use middleware to solve this specific problem.
Check https://docs.nestjs.com/middleware

The middleware could look like this (did not test it):

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';
import {Inject, Injectable,NestMiddleware} from '@nestjs/common';
import * as http from 'http';
import { WINSTON_MODULE_PROVIDER } from 'nest-winston';
import { Logger } from 'winston';

@Injectable()
export class LoggerMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
    constructor(@Inject(WINSTON_MODULE_PROVIDER) private readonly logger: Logger) {
    }

    public use(request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction): void {
        const {body, method, originalUrl, headers} = request;
        this.logger.log({body, method, originalUrl, headers})

    }
}
```

And you could apply it like this:

```
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
    public configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer): void {
        consumer
            .apply(LoggerMiddleware)
            .forRoutes('*');
    }
}
```